# How to zipalign .zip folder from Appery.io

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play, appery.io

When I hit the export to Android Studio (.apk) button on my first, very simple app in Appery.io, I expected it to download a .apk file (like it claimed) that I could upload to Google Play.

But instead, that button gives me a .zip file (which, after about 2 hours of pounding my fingers onto the keyboard, I figured out I was supposed to RENAME it to a .apk instead of find the .apk file somewhere in the directory by going deep into my pc settings) that is rejected for not being zip aligned. And so I made a mock app with one button that opened up a second blank page, hit the same export button and got the same product.

So why is there nothing about renaming the .zip to a .apk and nothing about the fact that the file is not zipaligned in any of Appery's tutorials?

I have spent about 10 hours researching, watching tutorials, downloading this program, then that one, then the other program I need to make that other one run so that this other thing can happen because that file over there doesn't like the file over here which doesn't work because this program's .exe was too big and I had to move all my files onto my other computer's hard disk, which I had to take apart in order to access, which didn't help because then the .exe decided to take a vacation, which was OK because this other site thought I needed to download a completely different program which installed but didn't help because the file it needs to like is holding a grudge ----- and have gotten absolutely NOWHERE.

Can anyone tell me how to zip align a .zip downloaded right from Appery.io - or even better show me a step by step workflow from that export button to Google Play dev. console?

Or is that button there just for decoration?

Programs I have installed: a whole bunch of Java do-nothing stuff, Android Studio (complete package), and Eclipse "Jee Mars"

The type of app is jQuery, if that helps.

[screeny 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xobdl.png)   [screeny 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sAyt.png)

Comment: It may be that I just don't know the Android dev environment, but your fourth para (about how long you've spent on this thing) is quite confusing - can you compress the information here into a couple of line? If readers are confused by your question after a few minutes of reading they may not answer, so make things as succinct as you can!

Comment: Is [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/zipalign_tool) any good?

Answer (score 0):

If you click Android studio project, you will get java project files that can be imported into Android Studio or Eclipse. From there on you will have to create your apk to upload on play store.
If you need apk from Appery  to be able to directly upload to plaster, click on binary('api) option coming on right of anndroid studio and you will get your api which can be upload directly. Or even installed on devices.